# Как добавить dots(точки под слайдером для переключения между слайдами) к слайдеру?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Есть слайдер, как добавить к нему dots?(точки под слайдером для переключения между слайдами) уже голову сломал, помогите пожалуйста.
[image: вот так выглядит]

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var slide = $('.slider-single');
  var slideTotal = slide.length - 1;
  var slideCurrent = -1;

  function slideInitial() {
    slide.addClass('proactivede');
    setTimeout(function() {
      slideRight();
    }, 500);
  }

  function slideRight() {
    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      slideCurrent++;
    } else {
      slideCurrent = 0;
    }

    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent - 1);
    } else {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideTotal);
    }
    var activeSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent);
    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent + 1);
    } else {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(0);

    }

    slide.each(function() {
      var thisSlide = $(this);
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('preactivede')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactive').addClass('proactivede');
      }
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('preactive')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactive active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactivede');
      }
    });
    preactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactive');
    activeSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive proactive proactivede').addClass('active');
    proactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactivede').addClass('proactive');
  }

  function slideLeft() {
    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      slideCurrent--;
    } else {
      slideCurrent = slideTotal;
    }

    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent + 1);
    } else {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(0);
    }
    var activeSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent);
    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent - 1);
    } else {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideTotal);
    }
    slide.each(function() {
      var thisSlide = $(this);
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('proactivede')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactive active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactivede');
      }
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('proactive')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactive').addClass('proactivede');
      }
    });
    preactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactive');
    activeSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive proactive proactivede').addClass('active');
    proactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactivede').addClass('proactive');
  }
  var left = $('.slider-left');
  var right = $('.slider-right');
  left.on('click', function() {
    slideLeft();
  });
  right.on('click', function() {
    slideRight();
  });
  slideInitial();
});
```

```css
@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-container .slider-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: z-index 0ms 250ms;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-image {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #fdc84b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download:hover,
.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-title {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 16px 20px 0 0;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes i {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #ff6060;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  color: #787878;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes:hover,
.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactivede .slider-single-image {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-image {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translateX(-25%) scale(0.8);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-download {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-title {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-likes {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-image {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translateX(25%) scale(0.8);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-download {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-title {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-likes {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactivede .slider-single-image {
  transform: translateX(50%) scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active {
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-image {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-download {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-title {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-likes {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-likes i {
  animation-name: heartbeat;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-delay: 900ms;
  animation-interation: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slider-container .slider-left {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  right: 85%;
  top: 36%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-right: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-left: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  margin-right: -2px;
}

.slider-container .slider-right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  left: 85%;
  top: 36%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-right: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-left: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.menu-left {
  width: 84%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.menu-left h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ff7624;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.menu-left p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #424c5f;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

.menu-right {
  width: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="img/project_preview_1.png" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="img/project_preview_3.png" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="img/project_preview_2.png" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="slider-left" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
  <a class="slider-right" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Кто  сказал, что `z-index` поддается  `плавной трансформации`  `transition: z-index 0ms 250ms;`

Comment: И если честно не понимаю что такое `dots`

Comment: dots это точки под слайдером для переключения между слайдами.

Comment: Ну для начала вам нужен метод перехода на слайд по номеру. И через него будет работать и next и prev. Точки тогда будет уже просто сделать.

Comment: Если вы не изобретаете велосипед - проще использовать готовые настраиваемые решения вроде slick-slider или owl-carousel.

Comment: Я не изобретаю велосипед, мне нужен именно этот слайдер который я сделал и в целях обучения я хочу сделать именно для этого слайдера точки для переключения между слайдами. А о этих готовых решениях я в курсе и с ними уже работал, спасибо за ответ:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так... (То,что добавил, выделил комментариями)

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var slide = $('.slider-single');
  var slideTotal = slide.length - 1;
  var slideCurrent = -1;

  /* Функция добавления точек по количеству слайдов */
  var slideDotWrap = $('.slider-dot-wrapper');
  var slideDotRef = $('.slider-dot');

  function slideDotAdd() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slideTotal; i++) {
      slideDotWrap.append(slideDotRef.clone());
    };
    slideDotWrap.on('click', '.slider-dot', function() {
      slideCurrent = $(this).index() - 1;
      slideRight();
    });
    slideDotRef = $('.slider-dot');
  }
  /* Функция подсветки активной точки */
  function slideDotCurr() {
    $('div.slider-dot').css('background', 'none');
    slideDotRef.eq(slideCurrent).css('background', '#fdc84b');
  }
  /* ----- */

  function slideInitial() {
    slide.addClass('proactivede');
    slideDotAdd();
    setTimeout(function() {
      slideRight();
    }, 500);
  }

  function slideRight() {
    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      slideCurrent++;
    } else {
      slideCurrent = 0;
    }

    slideDotCurr(); // Подсвечиваем активную точку

    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent - 1);
    } else {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideTotal);
    }
    var activeSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent);
    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent + 1);
    } else {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(0);

    }

    slide.each(function() {
      var thisSlide = $(this);
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('preactivede')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactive').addClass('proactivede');
      }
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('preactive')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactive active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactivede');
      }
    });
    preactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactive');
    activeSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive proactive proactivede').addClass('active');
    proactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactivede').addClass('proactive');
  }

  function slideLeft() {
    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      slideCurrent--;
    } else {
      slideCurrent = slideTotal;
    }

    slideDotCurr(); // Подсвечиваем активную точку

    if (slideCurrent < slideTotal) {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent + 1);
    } else {
      var proactiveSlide = slide.eq(0);
    }
    var activeSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent);
    if (slideCurrent > 0) {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideCurrent - 1);
    } else {
      var preactiveSlide = slide.eq(slideTotal);
    }
    slide.each(function() {
      var thisSlide = $(this);
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('proactivede')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactive active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactivede');
      }
      if (thisSlide.hasClass('proactive')) {
        thisSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactive').addClass('proactivede');
      }
    });
    preactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede active proactive proactivede').addClass('preactive');
    activeSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive proactive proactivede').addClass('active');
    proactiveSlide.removeClass('preactivede preactive active proactivede').addClass('proactive');
  }
  var left = $('.slider-left');
  var right = $('.slider-right');
  left.on('click', function() {
    slideLeft();
  });
  right.on('click', function() {
    slideRight();
  });
  slideInitial();
});
```

```css
@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .slider-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: z-index 0ms 250ms;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-image {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #fdc84b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download:hover,
.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-download:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-title {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 16px 20px 0 0;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes i {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #ff6060;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.55, 1.43);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  color: #787878;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes:hover,
.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single .slider-single-likes:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactivede .slider-single-image {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-image {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translateX(-25%) scale(0.8);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-download {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-title {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.preactive .slider-single-likes {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-image {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translateX(25%) scale(0.8);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-download {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-title {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactive .slider-single-likes {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.proactivede .slider-single-image {
  transform: translateX(50%) scale(0);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active {
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-image {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-download {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-title {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-likes {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.slider-container .slider-content .slider-single.active .slider-single-likes i {
  animation-name: heartbeat;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-delay: 900ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slider-container .slider-left {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  right: 85%;
  top: 36%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-right: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-left: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  margin-right: -2px;
}

.slider-container .slider-right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  left: 85%;
  top: 36%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-right: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  border-left: 2px solid #fdc84b;
  margin-left: -2px;
}


/* Контейнер для точек */

.slider-container .slider-dot-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  bottom: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Точка */

.slider-container .slider-dot-wrapper .slider-dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px black;
}

.slider-container .slider-dot-wrapper .slider-dot:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fdd01c;
}


/*  */

.menu-left {
  width: 84%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.menu-left h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ff7624;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.menu-left p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #424c5f;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

.menu-right {
  width: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffaaaa/ffffff?text=1" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffcc66/ffffff?text=2" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-single">
      <img class="slider-single-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/00CED1/444444?text=3" alt="6" />
      <div class="square-1-project">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="slider-left" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
  <a class="slider-right" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
  <!-- Контейнер с dot-ами -->
  <div class="slider-dot-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-dot"></div>
  </div>
  <!--  -->
</div>
```

Comment: Да именно нужен переход по клику на точку, а так вообще отлично сделано, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @ZANYBHF готово. Проверяйте.

Comment: отлично работает, огромная благодарность!